# Using Matlab.engine and installing tensorflow at the same time

Tags: python, matlab, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

Currently I am working on a project with Jupyter Notebook in which I need to run a matlab script (.m) which includes a function that provides me with data which i try to solve with a tensorflow model afterwards. I can set up an environment that runs the matlab code an gives me the data and I can set up an environment that does the tensorflow thing but my problem is I can`t do it in the same environment.

Here is the setup and the problems. I am using matlab.engine which I installed like described here: https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/install-the-matlab-engine-for-python.html
To run my Jupyter Notebook I first navigate to the location where my python.exe and the matlab files are lying *("C:\Users\Philipp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts")*. If I try to run **pip install tensorflow** (in Anaconda Prompt) I got a lot of different errors like the following. Conda install works but even when it is installed i can`t import it.

`ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow.core'`  or
`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow` or just `No module named 'tensorflow'`

I searched for all those problems but nothing helped me. I think this has something to do with the directory I am working in and I know it is bad but I have no idea how to change that. The error also occurs in different environments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. For this I needed a Jupyter Notebook and an external .py script that I design as a Flask. I can luckily run those in different environments. I past and request the data from the server by using "get" and "post".

If someone still has another idea to do all this in one JN, I would still be happy about answers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running `!pip install tensorflow` directly in Jupyter Notebook? It's a temporary workaround, but I am having the same problems and this one helped. Remember to comment it out after installation, so you wont re-run it by accident.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately it didn't work: 
````ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)

ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow```